# How to split/subset a dataframe in R, edit data according to split, then reform dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a large data set that is in a data frame. Here is a sample (there are also several columns of covariates that I have omitted for brevity):

```
id  week
1   5
1   7
1   8
1   9
1   10
1   11
1   14
1   15
1   16
1   17
1   18
2   3
2   5
2   6
2   7
2   9
2   10
2   11
2   14
2   15
2   16
2   17
2   18
2   20
2   22
….. …..
8   8
11  8
14  8
16  8
18  8
21  8
22  8
25  8
26  8
27  8
36  8
37  8
3   9
4   9
5   9
7   9
8   9
9   9
10  9
11  9
14  9
15  9
17  9
18  9
22  9
23  9
```

I am conducting some survival analysis on these data and I need to manipulate the data in several ways.

First, I need to add a column "event" that takes the value 0 for all rows except the last row for each id. For example, for id=1, there would be a 1 in the row corresponding to week 18 and zero in the others. Then, so on for all approx. 3000 ids.
I have tried 'split' and 'subset' but I am running into problems getting the data back into the original data frame.

Secondly, I need a 'time' column that takes the value 1 for the first (minimum) value of week for each id, then counts up in the same increments as the week column. An example of these first two points is below, i.e. what I want to end up with. :

```
id  week event  time
1   5   0   1
1   7   0   3
1   8   0   4
1   9   0   5
1   10  0   6
1   11  0   7
1   14  0   10
1   15  0   11
1   16  0   12
1   17  0   13
1   18  1   14
2   3   0   1
2   5   0   3
2   6   0   4
2   7   0   5
2   9   0   7
2   10  0   8
2   11  0   9
2   14  0   12
2   15  0   13
2   16  0   14
2   17  0   15
2   18  0   16
2   20  0   18
2   22  1   20
```

Thirdly, I need to take this new data set and create a number of new columns: dummies for each 'week' period. I need 37 'week' dummy columns with a 1 in the cell corresponding to the 'week' row and week dummy column.

```
id  event   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7  d8  d9  covariate
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0.70
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0.56
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0.70
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0.16
```

I have been trying a lot of stuff, mainly on the first two points over the last couple of days and I am still on the steep part of the learning curve. Getting better though. Any thoughts/comments etc? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry- can't figure out how to get the example data to display well...

Comment: For future reference, highlight data and hit the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfN)[order(id, week), c("event", "time") := list(+(1:.N==.N),
                      cumsum(c(1,diff(week))))  ,id]
dfN
#    id week event time
# 1:  1    5     0    1
# 2:  1    7     0    3
# 3:  1    8     0    4
# 4:  1    9     0    5
# 5:  1   10     0    6
# 6:  1   11     0    7
# 7:  1   14     0   10
# 8:  1   15     0   11
# 9:  1   16     0   12
#10:  1   17     0   13
#11:  1   18     1   14
#12:  2    3     0    1
#13:  2    5     0    3
#14:  2    6     0    4
#15:  2    7     0    5
#16:  2    9     0    7
#17:  2   10     0    8
#18:  2   11     0    9
#19:  2   14     0   12
#20:  2   15     0   13
#21:  2   16     0   14
#22:  2   17     0   15
#23:  2   18     0   16
#24:  2   20     0   18
#25:  2   22     1   20
```

Or

```
setDT(dfN)[order(id, week), c("event", "time") := list(c(rep(0,.N-1), 1),
                      cumsum(c(1,diff(week))))  ,id]
```

For the third part of the question, we can use `dcast`

```
dfN[, week:=factor(week, levels=1:37)]
dfN[, N:= 1:.N]


 res <- dcast(dfN, N~week, value.var="time", length, drop=FALSE)[,
    c("id", "event") := dfN[, c("id", "event"), with=FALSE]][]

 res[1:4]
 #   N 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 id event
#1: 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1     0
#2: 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1     0
#3: 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1     0
#4: 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1     0
```

NOTE: The covariate was not shown in the example data

#### data

```
dfN <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
week = c(5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
22L)), .Names = c("id", "week"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! The first part of the code worked a treat. However, the second part is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to create 37 columns of dummy variables. with a 1 in the column corresponding to the week value, and a zero in the other columns. I'm looking into what exactly dcast is doing but the result does not seem to jive. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry- new to SO. Fixed it. I'm working on data.table now and learning a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
> df$event<-0
> df[c(which(diff(df$id)!=0),nrow(df)),"event"]<-1
> df$time<-(unlist(sapply(split(df,df$id),function(d){ cumsum(c(1,diff(d$week))) })))
> df
   id week event time
1   1    5     0    1
2   1    7     0    3
3   1    8     0    4
4   1    9     0    5
5   1   10     0    6
6   1   11     0    7
7   1   14     0   10
8   1   15     0   11
9   1   16     0   12
10  1   17     0   13
11  1   18     1   14
12  2    3     0    1
13  2    5     0    3
14  2    6     0    4
15  2    7     0    5
16  2    9     0    7
17  2   10     0    8
18  2   11     0    9
19  2   14     0   12
20  2   15     0   13
21  2   16     0   14
22  2   17     0   15
23  2   18     0   16
24  2   20     0   18
25  2   22     1   20
```

Or if you want to go the split-edit-reform way:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$id),function(x){ 
    y<-cbind(x,event=0); y[nrow(x),ncol(x)+1]<-1; 
    z<-cbind(y,time=cumsum(c(1,diff(x$week)))); z }))
```

For the third part, if you want all the way to 37 weeks (corresponding to columns 'd1' to 'd37'):

```
> result<-t(apply(df,1,function(x){ 
    tmp<-rep(0,37); names(tmp)<-paste0("d",1:37); 
    tmp[x["week"]]=1; c(x["id"],x["event"], tmp) }))
> result
      id event d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d14 d15 d16 d17 d18
 [1,]  1     0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [2,]  1     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [3,]  1     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [4,]  1     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 

       d19 d20 d21 d22 d23 d24 d25 d26 d27 d28 d29 d30 d31 d32 d33 d34 d35 d36
 [1,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [2,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [3,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [4,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

       d37
 [1,]   0
 [2,]   0
 [3,]   0
 [4,]   0
```